# can't convert Regexp to String (TypeError) Cucumber rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, cucumber

I got the following error when I tried implementing a step definition;
**WARNING: Using 'Given/When/Then' in step definitions is deprecated, use 'step' to call other steps instead**
Below are my movie steps

```
Given /the following movies exist/ do |movies_table|
  movies_table.hashes.each do |movie| 
  Movie.create!(movie)
 end

Then(/^the director of "(.*?)" should be "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  movie = Movie.find_by_arg1(arg1)
  movie.arg2.should == arg2**
end
```

end

It failed on the then statement and requested me to substitute 'then' with 'step' which i didbut ended up with the same error!
So my question is how do I convert the 'Then' use case into a 'step' definition? i tried several ways but all failed!!! Can some one out there help me or point me to the right direction I am kinda new to this...

Comment: Hi Ian I appreciate you timely response! I tried without the brackets and got the same result/error!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Given is not properly terminated - its missing an end:

```
Given /the following movies exist/ do |movies_table|
  movies_table.hashes.each do |movie| 
    Movie.create!(movie)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Ian when I run the Given statement without the then statement it passes with the 2 ends! However with the then statement including 2 ends it fails..

Comment: the then statement looked ok - you need to match each `do` with an `end`

Comment: Its OK but rails/cucumber will not accept it bcse it doesn't follow the normal protocol of Given/When/Then, cucumber asks to implement this statement without 'then'!!!! offers a suggestion to use 'step' my qn is how do I rewrite this statement using 'step' instead of then?

Comment: Hi Ian you were right to some extent(regarding the '2 ends') I resolved issue when I executed when I executed the 'when' and 'then' cases after implementing the 'Given' case which I had already figured out then all fell together... thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Given /the following xxx exist/ do |xxxx_table|
  xxxx_table.hashes.each do |xxxx| 
  xxxx.create!(xxxx)
 end
end

Then(/^the director of "(.*?)" should be "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  movie = xxxx.find_by_arg1(arg1)
  xxxx.arg2.should == arg2**
end